# Ansible with Windows node - How to create a directory

Tags: windows, ansible

I need to create `C:\MSI` folder to put there msi files. Here is my task:

```
tasks:
  - name: Copy *.msi files from ./MSI to C:\MSI
    file: path=C:\MSI state=directory
```

But I got the error:

```
TASK [Copy *.msi files from ./MSI to C:\MSI] ***********************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fatal: [agentsmith]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "The term '/usr/bin/python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."}
```

and in verbose mode I see that File module for some reason puts `/usr/bin/python` to the Powershell script:

```
TASK [Copy *.msi files from ./MSI to C:\MSI] ***********************************
task path: /home/qaexpert/ansible-lab/tcagent.yml:8
<agentsmith> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5986 TO agentsmith
<agentsmith> EXEC Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
(New-Item -Type Directory -Path $env:temp -Name "ansible-tmp-1477410445.62-187863101456896").FullName | Write-Host -Separator '';
<agentsmith> PUT "/tmp/tmpqOJYen" TO "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1477410445.62-187863101456896\file.ps1"
<agentsmith> EXEC Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
Try
{
/usr/bin/python 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1477410445.62-187863101456896\file.ps1'
}
Catch
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible looks for `/usr/bin/python` because the `file` module needs Python installed on the target system. It is not possible to use *normal* Ansible modules for Windows target.

Look at the [Ansible Windows documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#what-modules-are-available) for details. On Windows hosts only modules listed in the [“windows” subcategory of the Ansible module index](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_windows_modules.html) are available.

To replace the regular `file` module use the `win_file` module.